# java/android OutputStream blocks, but not long enough when using sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, block, outputstream

So, I'm writing an application, that takes an image, and immediately sends it to a remote computer, using sockets.

```
OutputStream mStream;

mStream = mySocket.getOutputStream();

/* filling header/bmbytes*/
mStream.write(header);
mStream.write(BitmapBytes);

mStream.flush(); //not working?

/*try { 
    wait(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {

}*/
mStream.close();
```

The write functions work perfectly, until the last few kilobytes. A random amount of data is not sent (about 295 kb of 300 kb is good). As I read it's because it blocks until it buffers all the data, but it doesn't seem to care whether data is actually sent, so mStream.close() is called too soon. If I uncomment the wait section, it works perfectly, but I might need to call more than one time per second, and it's still unreliable(depending on the connection), so i need an other way to call close() properly. Flush doesn't seem to do anything. Am I using it wrong?
Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you sure the problem is on the write side and not the read side?

Comment: The simplest cause would be that the input is not read fully, missing a close or so. _(I am aware that this probably is too simple.)_

Answer (score 0):

This code sends all the data. The problem is at the receiving end.

The sleep and the flush are both pointless before the close.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this example http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk

Try to send data by portions not all at ones.
Like:

```
while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that code waits for the answer, thus it's guaranteed that all data is sent. And my pic is smaller than 1 MB which is the size of the packets used there. I need to close the conn in order to tell the receiver that the transmission is over, but like this the last few bytes are lost. The idea was good, just wouldn't work, thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to send something bigger >2Mb, how much data is lost?  OS Version? Is upload done in a separate thread?

Comment: Classic misuse of `available(),` and there is no need to 'send data by portions'.